# Loosing my entire session data after redirecting to new page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, session

Don't know why my code isn't working. which ever ways I tried I am loosing my session data after control goes to second page. I am pasting entire code here some one please help.

Page:1

```html
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hbase- login</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hbase.css"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> 
        <script src="../hbase-bl.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container-fluid header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>hbase!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid main">
            <form class="logformblock" action="hbase-details.php" method="post">
                <div class="row col-xs-12"><h2>Login</h2></div>
                <div class="row valid9">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><label>nick name</label></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="uname" value="" placeholder="nick name">
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="row valid9">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><label>password</label></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input class="inputstyle" type="password" name="upswd" value="" placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row ">
<!--                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><label>&nbsp;</label></div>-->
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                         <input value="Y" type="checkbox" name="cbox">
                         <span class="checkboxstyle">Keep me logged in</span>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="row errmsg">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><small style="color: red;">please enter complete credentials</small>  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="buttonstyle" type="button" id="rbutton" value="submit">submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> 
                       forgot password?
                    </a> 
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span style="font-size: small;"> New user? </span>
                    <a href="/hbase-reg.html"> 
                        <span style="font-size: large;"> Sign-up </span>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Note:</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>All your citizenship details are stored with us.Log in using your nickname to retrieve the same.</p>
                
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="row">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
        </form>   
        </div>
        <div class="gapper"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer">&COPY; copy rights. All rights reserved @hbase!</div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['uname'];
           $_SESSION['upswd'] = $_POST['upswd'];
        }   
           exit();
           
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page:2

```html
<?php
   session_start();
   var_dump($_SESSION);  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>registration Confirmation</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hbase.css"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <?php 
           $my_connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","testtest");
           $link_db = mysql_select_db("killerphp",$my_connect);

           if (!($my_connect && $link_db)) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
               mysql_close($my_connect);
          }
        ?>  

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-11">
                    <h1>hbase!</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-1 sub3">
                    <a href="/hbase-logout.html">logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="details">
                    <?php 
                        $uname = $_SESSION["uname"];
                        $upswd = $_SESSION["upswd"];
                        $query = "select * from hmailsup where nickname='$uname' AND password='$upswd'";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        if (!$result){
                            echo "<h1>Something went wrong!</h1><br>";
                            echo "<p>server may be down or not responding.please try again later</p>";
                            mysql_close($my_connect);
                        }else{
                          $rrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                          if ($rrows     == 0){
                              echo "<h1>It seems you haven't registered with us</h1>";
                              echo "<p>Please <a href='/hbase-reg.html'>sign-up</a> here";
                          }
                          else{
                              echo "<h1>Dear citizen, Your details are as follows</h1>";
                              echo "<p><strong>Note:</strong><br>please dont share below details at your maximum possibility.As it may lead to misuse.<br><h4>Have a great stay!</h4></p><br>";
                              $html = "<div class='container'>";
                              $html .= "<div class='col-md-3 hidden-xs'></div>";
                              $html .= "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 mydetails'>";        
                              $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                              foreach($row as $key => $value){
                                 if ($key == 'Firstname' || $key == 'Lastname'
                                         || $key == 'Email' || $key == 'Mobile'){ 
                                    $html .= "<div class='row subdetails'><div class='col-xs-6 col-md-6'><strong>$key:</strong></div>" . "<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-6'>$value</div></div>";
                                 }      
                              }
                          }
                        }
                        $html .= "</div>"; 
                        $html .= "<div class='col-md-3 hidden-xs'></div>";
                        $html .= "</div>";
                        echo $html;
                        mysql_close($my_connect);
                     ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gapper"></div>
        <div class="row container-fluid">
            <div class="footer">&COPY; copy rights. All rights reserved @hbase!</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see NULL when var_dump is printed. 
And it is working fine if I access pages separately. I am facing issue only during redirect.

Comment: I don't see any code which redirects from page 1 to page 2.

Comment: I have never solved this issue, im new to PHP and I'd love to see why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Akshay its in the forms action, I see it.

Comment: @sri
What are these file names? What is the name of page1 and page2? Which is `hbase-details.php?`

Comment: simple, this will never happen `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` therefore nothing gets set.

Comment: @Akshay page1 = hbase-login.php, page2 = hbase-details.php

Comment: @Fred -ii-  Thanks. Please tell me how to solve it then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- even if I remove conditional statement, it doesn't work. I added that IF statement after I see one of the solutions from another discussion.

Comment: Guys, I am able to solve this issue myself. I just moved session assignment to hbase-details.php (second page) and put IF isset condition there. It is working fine now. Thanks for your time.